# Select options using jquery not behaving as expected

Tags: java, jquery

I have got a select option like the following

```
<select name="test" onchange="updateRecipientCount()">
<option value='123'>one</option>
</select>
```

When I click and select an option it behaves normal and I can submit the form without any issue.

Now after my recent change which is remotely selecting my option via jQuery (get its value from another field, say autocomplete, and select it in the options, based on the value), even though I can see it selected on the screen, it does not behave as it should.

```
 $('select option[value='123']').attr('selected', true);
```

When I submit the form I get the following error and also it does not trigger the select onchange function.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Index Value
```

Does anyone have an idea what is the problem here? Why this error happens when I select my options using jquery?!

Comment: If you've full control over your HTML markup, then @Hardik Mishra's answer is the better approach.

Comment: I need to do also multi select. Its like the page needs an actual click. otherwise it does not work

Comment: how is the form submission happening? is it an ajax submit

Answer (score 0):

Add `id` attribute to your `select`.

```
<select name="test" id="test" onchange="updateRecipientCount()">

$('#test').val(123); //this will select the option with value 123.
```

**Multiselect Example:**

```
<select name="test" id="test" onchange="updateRecipientCount();" multiple="multiple">
<option value='123'>one</option>
<option value='123'>two</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    updateRecipientCount();  // For testing
});

function updateRecipientCount(){
    var ary = [123, 123]; // test data
    $("#test").val(ary);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Does it let me to do multi select using your solution?

Comment: For multi select you need to pass multiple values as array.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the quotes in the selector wrong, also `attr` selected's value should be `selected`:

```
$('select option[value="123"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: no issue with the select. its like the page needs an actual click to perform normal!